# Hover command stops working when hiding nested div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use the hover command in CSS and it works when hovering over my property button, but I want it to hide after the `click` event in JavaScript.

Below is an example of my code with a "property" button and then a dropdown that comes when you hover over it. If I add `$(".dropdown-content").css("display","none");` to the button click event then the hover command stops working.

I don't understand why this is the case as I would be hiding a nested div `.dropdown-content` and so the hover command should still work for the outer div `.dropdown but it doesn't. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
$("#001").on('click', function() {
  window.whichtab = 1;
});

$("#002").on('click', function() {
  window.whichtab = 2;
});

$("#001,#002").on('click', function() {
  $("#title1,#title2").hide()
  
  if (window.whichtab == 1) { //home
    $("#title1").show();
    $("#title1").css("display", "inline");
    //$(".dropdown-content").css("display","none");
  }
  
  if (window.whichtab == 2) {
    $("#title2").show();
    $("#title2").css("display", "inline");
    //$(".dropdown-content").css("display","none");
  }
});
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3d70b2;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown-content button {
  color: black;
  border: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 13px 16px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-color: #3d70b2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: 17, 83, 238;
  min-width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3d70b2;
}

#title1 {
  display: inline;
}

#title2 {
  /*defult title is hidden for 2*/
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <!--title of each tab-->
  <button class="dropbtn">Property</button>
  <h4 id="title1"> &emsp;&emsp;Home page</h4>
  <h4 id="title2"> &emsp;&emsp;Content Page</h4>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <!--each button going to each tab-->
    <button id="001" ,class='noHover'>Home Page</button><br>
    <button id="002">Content Page</button><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`display: none` doesn't preserve the space and you can not hover on that. You can use `opacity` property like the following way:

```
$(".dropdown-content").css("opacity", 0); // hide
$(".dropdown-content").css("opacity", 1); // show
```

Comment: This has the same effect, the hover command stops working. Also if I add visibility:visible; to the hover CSS it still remains not working.

Comment: @BenGooding, please try with *opacity*:)

Comment: It still doesn't work it, the dropdown-content becomes opacity 0 permanently and won't return back to 1 even if I add opacity: 1; in the CSS hover command

Comment: Also using   display: none   I thought should only effect the inner nested div as that is the one being removed, but the hover command stops working for the outer div